# What's wrong with this View in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, ios15

could someone help me figure out what's wrong within this view? Can you see the status bar and bottom view refreshing like crazy? I've tried several things like playing with paddings and margins without success.
What seems to be triggering the bug is adding the fifth element on the tab bar but i cannot realize what's wrong with it, can you?

Thanks for your help

```
import SwiftUI

struct TabManager: View {
@State var selectedTab = "house"
@State var edge = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets

var body: some View{
    
    ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .center, vertical: .bottom)) {
        
        switch selectedTab {
        case "house" :
            HomeView()
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .bottom)
        case "bookmark.circle":
            BookingView()
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .bottom)
        case "square.and.pencil":
            BookingsHistoryView()
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .bottom)
        case "gear":
            SettingsView()
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .bottom)
        default:
            HomeView()
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .bottom)
        }

        
        HStack(spacing: 0){
            
            ForEach(tabs,id: \.self){image in
                
                TabButton(selectedTab: $selectedTab, image: image)
                
                // equal spacing...
                
                if image != tabs.last{
                    
                    Spacer(minLength: 0)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal,25)
        .background(Color("panel"))
        .clipShape(Capsule())
        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.15), radius: 5, x: 5, y: 5)
        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.15), radius: 5, x: -5, y: -5)
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .padding(.bottom,edge!.bottom == 0 ? 20 : 0)
    }
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)
    .background(Color("background").ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all))
}
}

var tabs = ["house","bookmark.circle","square.and.pencil","gear","gear"]

struct TabButton : View {

@Binding var selectedTab : String

var image : String

var body: some View{
    
    Button(action: {selectedTab = image}) {
        
        Image(systemName: image)
            .renderingMode(.template)
            .foregroundColor(selectedTab == image ? Color("component") : Color(.label).opacity(0.4))
            .font(.system(size: 32))
            .padding()
    }
}
}
```

[image: SwiftUI Bug]

Comment: maybe you can note ``.padding(.bottom,edge!.bottom == 0 ? 20 : 0)`` to have a try

Comment: Try adding `edgesIgnoringSafeAreas()`

Comment: Try replacing all `.ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .bottom)` with `edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)`